# Why can my gentoo systemd installation only execute files as root?

Tags: permissions, users, login, gentoo, systemd

If I try to login as any other user, via `su` it says 'permission denied'. If I use `su -l` it says 'canot cd to `/home/<user>`'.
Logging in via the tty just kicks anyone without a message out except root.
If I try to install somthing via portage, it says 'permission denied to `/usr/bin/sandbox`'.

When I try to run `gdm`, it just shows a black screen.
Also, I get an error when trying `sudo -u <username> [a command]` as root. It says:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

This guy seems to have had a [similar problem](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/48437-only-root-can-execute-files-regardless-permissions.html) in 2005. However, nobody helped him out.

This is [my kernel configuration](https://github.com/jappeace/linux-config). However, I don't think that is the problem.

I've literally searched for hours. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `stat / /etc`?

Comment: @ChrisDown `chmod +x /` did the trick thanks, also this one helped: http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=3153&start=20#p19727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad permissions, either on `/` or `/etc`. Running this should fix it:

```
chmod 755 / /etc
chown root:root / /etc
```